# XCode build error "undefined reference for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

So I'm trying to link a static library to xcode and I keep getting this error: ld: '__ZN6Assimp8ImporterC2Ev' in /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-fgstrusvlsalcmaqizaayqhaluvj/Build/Products/Debug/libraryname.a(Importer.o) contains undefined reference for architecture x86_64
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

Has anyone here seen this error before and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: The static library isn't built for your architecture. Did you build it yourself or did you obtain it from somewhere else?

Comment: I downloaded it from online and then built it on xcode

Comment: What's the library? Do you think you might be missing some of the source files?

Comment: This is the link I downloaded from: https://bitbucket.org/sherief/open-asset-import it's a pre-compiled version of the open asset import library

Comment: Huh? Did you download the source code and build the .a file, or did you download the .a file from that site?

Comment: I downloaded the source code and built the .a file myself. It came with an xcodeproject included and so I just opened xcode, ran it and it created the .a file from there.

Comment: One observation is that this is a C++ library you're using. When you wrote below about "build with active architecture only" did you check the xcodeproj for the library, or for the program that's using it?

Comment: I checked both. They both said "yes." My main project is C++ as well.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have under "build with Active Architecture Only" in your project settings?

I'd also seem to remember having issues if you accidently add header files in with your "compile sources" under build phases.

Comment: "Build with active architeture only" just says "yes"